# How to create view for random url?

Tags: django

I'm in the process of accepting payments on my site and I have chosen to use Stripe. The way it works is that when the payment is finished or cancelled it redirects to a page depending on what happened. How can I create a view that checks for the GET parameter of my randomly generated url, so I can do my code stuff?

```
payment = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
  success_url="https://myurl.com/dashboard/payment/accepted/?id=MyvariableID",
  cancel_url="https://myurl.com/dashboard/payment/declined",
  payment_method_types=["card"],
  client_reference_id= stripeUID,
  line_items=[
    {
      "amount": 2000242,
      "quantity": 1,
      "name": "Blender rendering",
      "currency": "usd",
    }
  ]
)
```

So let's say that the users payment is confirmed and he's redirected to `success_url="https://myurl.com/dashboard/payment/accepted/?id=MyvariableID",`
How can I create a dynamic view that checks for the GET parameter ID so I can query some database stuff?

If there's a better way to do this then feel free to let me know. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can get `id` from the [`request.GET`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.GET) dict in the view.

Comment: But otherwise, a "random" parameter isn't any different from any other URL parameter.

Comment: @Alasdair Sorry mistake on my part with the `?id`. But how would I let django know that this view is for this random url? That's what im not sure about.

Comment: It sounds like you need to add a URL pattern like `path('/dashboard/payment/accepted/', payment_accepted, name='payment_accepted'),` - the querystring is not included.

Comment: @Alasdair Do I create a view then that looks something like this `def payment_accepted(request, payment_accepted):` And then my code under to capture the GET?

Comment: There are no captured values in `'/dashboard/payment/accepted/'`, so the view shouldn't have a `payment_accepted` argument: `def payment_accepted(request):`.

Comment: Got it. Thanks @Alasdair

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## ID as GET parameter

In the example above, your URL is always `https://myurl.com/dashboard/payment/accepted/`, as `?id=MyvariableID` is only a GET parameter.

Just create a simple URL path, something like this:

```
from yourapp import views

path('dashboard/payment/accepted/', views.accepted, name='accepted')
```

In your view you can access the parameter via `request.GET`. For example:

```
def accepted(request):
    payment_id = request.GET.get('id')

    if payment_id is not None:
        # do something
    else:
        # no payment ID found
```

This will return `None` if `id` isn't found, so you need to do exception management manually. You can also use this:

```
def accepted(request):
    try:
        payment_id = request.GET['id']
        # verify payment ID
    except KeyError:
        # no payment ID found
```

## ID as part of the URL

If you want the ID as part of the URL, then things look a bit different. First of all, your URL config looks something like this:

```
from yourapp import views

path('dashboard/payment/accepted/<payment_id>/', views.accepted, name='accepted')
```

Your view gets the `payment_id` from the URL as argument:

```
def accepted(request, payment_id):
    # verify payment ID
```

Btw. you probably want to change the `<payment_id>` in [`path`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/urls/#path) to `<int:payment_id>` if you're expecting an `int`. Or you can use [`re_path`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/urls/#re-path) and even do a regular expression check for better matching.

Comment: This answers what is was confused about. Thanks. I have one issue, and that is when visiting the URL it doesn't find the path. `The current path, dashboard/payment/accepted/64ab15e8-bc83-4281-beda-9c90ab4edcaa, didn't match any of these` . I've added your urls.py and views.py

Comment: Did you include your `urls.py` in the root url config, or edit it directly? If you run in debug mode and you get an 404, you should see all available URL's directly above your error message `The current path, dashboard/payment/accepted/64ab15e8-bc83-4281-beda-9c90ab4edcaa, didn't match any of these`.

Comment: Your `settings` module will most likely have a `ROOT_URLCONF` variable, which points to the root URL config. Either add your URL `path()` in this config, or create your own `urls.py` and include that in the root config like in this example: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/urls/#path

Comment: Nope didn't include it in my Projects urls. Only in my app's. That will probably fix it once I add it there. Thanks. :-)